# Collection implementation that mostly delegates to a class member

Tags: java

I want to implement a `Collection` that represents a sorted collection of items. The main reason i need a special `Collection` instead of just calling `sort()` on a list is that i need specific behavior for the `add()` method to improve performance. The rest of the `Collection` will mostly just delegate to a class member, probably an `ArrayList`.

Is there a way to delegate part of the `Collection` interface to my class member instead of having to write all the delegation by hand like this?

```
public void clear() {
    myList.clear();
}

public int hashCode() {
    return myList.hashCode()
}

...
```

Comment: Your class can extend ArrayList, so you'll only have to override `add()`.

Comment: The list interface expects items to be added at the end of the list. My add method will not do that 100% of the time. I updated the question.

Comment: @Eran: Maybe also `addAll` and `set` and some others (if you are going to use these and they don't just delegate to `add` internally).

Comment: in this case, maybe `extend AbstractCollection` instead. Then you don't have to adhere to the `List` interface.

Comment: Also: Why not just use `TreeSet`? Because you want to allow duplicates?

Comment: AbstractCollection is just what i needed! I want a collection with constant insertion time at the end. O(logn) would probably suffice, but the data sets might become quite large, so i want the constant time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Eran you can extend an ArrayList and the methods which adds elements to the underlying collection.

However, as mentioned by Spotted in the comments below this will introduce some unnecessary methods.

What you can do instead is to inherit the AbstractCollection class and delegate the calls to an internal class.

An example:

```
import java.util.AbstractCollection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Collection;

public class MyCustomCollection<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> {

    private Collection<E> delegate = new ArrayList<E>();

    private void myCustomBehaviour() {
        // TODO: Implement.
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.delegate.size();
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return delegate.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        myCustomBehaviour();

        return delegate.add(e);
    }
}
```

The above solution is cleaner than using an ArrayList because we are not interested in anything but the functionality specified in the Collection interface.

The AbstractCollection is a partial implementation of the Collection interface of which there are several. Some of which are HashSet, HashMap, LinkedList and more.

Comment: I will subclass AbstractCollection as suggested by Thilo, since a list is not quite what i need, but the solution will look similar.

Comment: Extending `ArrayList` (therefore `List`) conflicts with the user needs, namely a sorted collection. Concretly, how would you implement `add(int index, E element)` ?

Comment: You could throw an UnsupportedOperationException and be over with it. The user needs the specification from the Collection interface which means that the mentioned methods should never be called in the first place. A cleaner solution would be to use the AbstractCollection class. I have updated the answer accordingly. Good comment.

Comment: Other question from your edit: why overriding `remove(Object)` ?

Comment: Didn't realize that the AbstractCollection took care of that via the iterator.